# Insert code chunk in R Markdown with yasnippet and polymode

Tags: yasnippet, ess, polymode

I am trying to write a yasnippet to insert code chunks into an R Markdown file. I use polymode to have multiple major modes (markdown, ESS[S]) in a single file. This is my snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: chunk
# key: chunk
# --
\`\`\`{r $1}
$0
\`\`\`
```

When I try to insert the snippet into a .Rmd file in markdown mode, I get this error:

```
Error in post-command-hook (yas--post-command-handler): (error "Marker points into wrong buffer" #<marker at 7 in test.Rmd>)
```

The snippet does appear and my cursor is in the correct spot (right before the second curly brace):

````
```{r }

```
````

When I hit tab I get the following:

```
yas-next-field: Wrong type argument: overlayp, nil
```

I am guessing that I'm running into an interaction with polymode: I'm in markdown mode when I insert the snippet, but then polymode converts the contents of the code chunk to ESS[S] mode. It looks like there will eventually be a command to [insert a new chunk](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode/blob/a29b8a07cc9081bd75114d68fc7afdcef2e5bc94/polymode.el#L222-L224) in polymode, but in the meantime is there any way to get this snippet working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue, and wrote a stand-alone function to get around the weird interactions between `yasnippet` and `polymode`.

The following function mimics the behaviour of the snippet you tried, prompting first for the header info, which gets inserted at your `$1`, and then dropping you in the chunck body (your `$0`):

````el
(defun tws-insert-r-chunk (header) 
  "Insert an r-chunk in markdown mode. Necessary due to interactions between polymode and yas snippet" 
  (interactive "sHeader: ") 
  (insert (concat "```{r " header "}\n\n```")) 
  (forward-line -1))
````

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm an avid emacs user but familiar with lisp, Can you describe how you implement this function Rmd workflow??

Comment: Put the code in your .emacs file, so it gets loaded every time you start Emacs. Then you can call it via `M-x tws-insert-r-chunk`. Probably you will want to bind this command to a keyboard shortcut - there are lots of questions here about setting keybindings.